# Android Table is too wide for the screen

Tags: android, json, android-volley, tabular

I am using volley to retrieve my Json data from my webservice and populate the table rows. However the table is too wide for the screen it appears like this:
 [image]

As shown the right side of the table goes off screen. What are my options here, I would like to use a horizontal scroll as a last resort.

Comment: In your case, you could make your text smaller but that is about it, then you will see it won't work on all devices. The best option is to wrap it in a `HorizontalScrollView` for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: The text is already really small, the image of the table does not help. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Keep in mind its not uncommon to scroll tables on mobile phones. If you don't need to display in a table you have a ton of options. ListView, GridView, RecyclerView, basically anything that uses an Adapter

Comment: Thanks a lot I will look into them now

Comment: Apart from the what @inner_class7 has already suggested, you could try replacing the column header with single character labels like A, B, C and providing a legend for the same. You could also try splitting the table up into multiple tables. Yet another approach would be to only scroll the non-key columns.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will most likely split the table into multiples. I’m choosing this just because using a legend still doesn’t guarantee that the table won’t go off screen on smaller devices. Much appreciated @Karan Modi